Some android devices having the animation blue color developed by unity
this a project of mine. the issue is like I have multiple mobile devices. but one device my sprite animation shows in blue color. but if the same object has different animation its working fine.

I changed the Renderer pipeline still the issue is facing. I am now using Unity 2020.3.25f1.now only one device having this issue from I tested. I don't know many devices having the issue.
the tested device name is: OPPO A55(6GB RAM)
